# How do I get my steps variable to automatically change according to HealthKit in my view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, healthkit

In my Home view, I am displaying the number of steps the user has taken through the HealthKit API. However when the steps increase, the view does not change.

It only updates itself to the latest step value when the view is initialised again.

How can I make it update without having to initialise the view again?

Here is my code:

```
struct Home: View {
    
    @StateObject var healthStore = HealthStore()
    @State private var stepData: [StepData] = []
    
    private func updateUIFromStatistics(_ statisticsCollection: HKStatisticsCollection) {
        let startDate = Date()
        let endDate = Date()
        healthStore.steps = []
        
        statisticsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: endDate) { (statistics, stop) in
            let count = statistics.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: .count())
            let step = Step(count: Int(count ?? 0), date: statistics.startDate)
            healthStore.steps.append(step)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            if let firstStep = healthStore.steps.first {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("\(firstStep.count)")
                       
                    
                    
                    Text("Steps")
                        
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            healthStore.requestAuthorization { success in
                if success {
                    healthStore.calculateSteps { statisticsCollection in
                        if let statisticsCollection = statisticsCollection {
                            // update the UI
                            updateUIFromStatistics(statisticsCollection)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is HealthStore:

```
class HealthStore: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
    @Published var query: HKStatisticsCollectionQuery?
    @Published var steps = [Step]()
    
    init() {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            healthStore = HKHealthStore()            
        }
    }
        
    func calculateSteps(completion: @escaping (HKStatisticsCollection?) -> Void) {
       let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
       let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
       let anchorDate = Date.mondayAt12AM()
       let daily = DateComponents(day: 1)
       let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
       let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                     [.init(format: "metadata.%K != YES", HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered), predicate]
                                 )
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(
             quantityType: stepType,
             quantitySamplePredicate: compoundPredicate,
             options: .cumulativeSum,
             anchorDate: anchorDate,
             intervalComponents: daily)
          self.query!.initialResultsHandler = { [weak self] query, statisticsCollection, error in
             guard let self = self else { return }
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(statisticsCollection)
             }
          }
          self.query!.statisticsUpdateHandler = { [weak self] query, statistics, collection, error in
             guard let self = self else { return }
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let stepCount = statistics?.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()) {
                   self.steps.append(Step(count: Int(stepCount), date: statistics!.startDate))
                }
             }
          }
          if let healthStore = self.healthStore, let query = self.query {
             healthStore.execute(query)
          }
       }
    }
    
    func requestAuthorization(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
        
        guard let healthStore = self.healthStore else { return completion(false) }
        
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [stepType]) { (success, error) in
            completion(success)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobserverquery